# SQL query for download count

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I need a query which will get number of downloads for file. Table is like this

```
fid  uid        ip
21    0      111.111.111.11
21    0      222.222.222.22
21    0      111.111.111.11
21    1      333.333.333.33
21    1      111.111.111.11
21    1      444.444.444.44
21    2      555.555.555.55
22    0      111.111.111.11
```

uid is user id and if it's 0 user is anonymous.
Query should count number of rows where fid is 21<strike>, but with distinct values of ips if users are anonymous and distinct values of users AND ips if they are registered.( If user download a file, logs out, and download again as anonymous, query should count this as 1 download)</strike>

In this example, query should count something like this

```
fid  uid        ip
21    0      111.111.111.11
21    0      222.222.222.22
21    1      333.333.333.33
21    2      555.555.555.55
```

and result should be 4.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: I strikethrough some description, because it's confusing. 
Thanks for all the comments and possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query gets the grouping you want, except that I don't know the business rule that determined `333.333.333.33` should be returned for `uid=1`. I opted to use `MAX(ip)` instead:

```
select distinct t.uid, t.ip
from MyTable t
inner join (
  select uid, max(ip) maxip
  from MyTable
  where fid = 21
  group by uid
) tm on t.uid = tm.uid
and ((t.uid <> 0 and t.ip = tm.maxip) or t.uid = 0)
where t.fid = 21
```

[SQL Fiddle Example #1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a26a/11)

You can then wrap it in a count, like this:

```
select count(*)
from (
  select distinct t.uid, t.ip
  from MyTable t
  inner join (
    select uid, max(ip) maxip
    from MyTable
    where fid = 21
    group by uid
  ) tm on t.uid = tm.uid
  and ((t.uid <> 0 and t.ip = tm.maxip) or t.uid = 0)
  where t.fid = 21
) a
```

[SQL Fiddle Example #2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a26a/20)

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like:

```
    SELECT count(distinct ip) FROM table WHERE fid = 21;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you need:

```
select fid, count(*) as uipcount, sum(rowcount) as rowcount
from (select fid, userid, ip, count(*) as rowcount
      from t
      where fid = 21
      group by fid, userid, ip
     ) tsum
group by fid
```

The field uipcount is what you are looking for.  It also includes the total number of rows in the original data, as a bonus.

By the way, your condition "distinct values of ips if users are anonymous and distinct values of users AND ips if they are registered" is equivalent to "distinct values of users and ips for everyone".  All anonymous users have the same userid, so including their userid in the distinct doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your explanation and your sample data do not correlate, you state "distinct values of users AND ips if they are registered", yet it your sample data registered users only show once despite having different IPs. Based on your sample data this will work:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN UID = 0 THEN IP ELSE CAST(UID AS VARCHAR) END) AS UniqueDownloads,
        COUNT(*) AS TotalDownloads
FROM    T
WHERE   FID = 21
```

But based on your description, this will work:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS UniqueDownloads,
        SUM(Downloads) AS TotalDownloads
FROM    (   SELECT  UID, IP, COUNT(*) AS Downloads
            FROM    T
            WHERE   FID = 21
            GROUP BY UID, IP
        ) T
```